# Redirect para link externo no Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para redireccionar para fora do meu website no Laravel?
Já tentei com Redirect::away() mas não deu. Vi umas soluções com javascript mas queria procurar outras formas.

Comment: Qual o conteúdo do `$location->url`?

Comment: @RFL www.google.pt

Comment: Eduardo, evite colocar código em imagens. Copie o código para a pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com a imagem inserida na pergunta, é possível ver que o valor de `$location->url` é "www.google.pt".

O valor não contém o protocolo, ou seja, não informa se o protocolo é `http`, `https`, etc...

Quando isso ocorre, o browser entende que o valor inserido na propriedade `href` é relativo a atual URL, ou seja:

- Atual URL: http://localhost/manage/shops/
- Valor agregado sem protocolo: www.google.pt
- URL final: http://localhost/manage/shops/www.google.pt

Se adicionar uma barra no ínicio, sem protocolo, o browser entende que o valor inserido na propriedade `href` é relativo ao domínio:

- Atual URL: http://localhost/manage/shops/
- Domínio: http://localhost
- Valor agregado sem protocolo e com barra: /www.google.pt
- URL final: http://localhost/www.google.pt

Para resolver a questão, é necessário inserir o protocolo desejado, por exemplo, o protocolo `https`:

```
<small><a href="https://{{ $location->url }}" target="_blank">Url mapa</a><small>
```

Entretanto, se é um sistema dinâmico, o protocolo não deve ser definido no HTML, uma vez que o mesmo pode ser diferente para cada URL.

Comment: É isso mesmo, obrigado!